# django 1.11 app can't find style.css in static/app/style.css dir

Tags: django, django-1.11

my app dir:

[image]

settings.py:

[image]

[image]

my base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'sns/style.css' %}" />
```

style.css content:

```
li a {
    color: green;
}
```

for some reason, I get a 404 when it tries to load style.css

[image]

page source:

[image]

Not sure what im missing?

UPDATE:

So I managed to get it working thanks for the helpful below comments :)

[image]

so those are my settings which I use before running

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

and my static content is generated hooray!

[image]

I had to update my html template to point to

[image]

before it was pointing to:

[image]

So this is my new problem. I don't think it's a good idea to have my style.css in the root of /static/. I want it to be in /static/sns/style.css but I don't know why django is putting it in the root dir.

UPDATE 2:

Hooray found the answer! Posting here in case anyone else wants to use it. All I had to do was add my app "sns" the settings.INSTALLED_APPS

[image]

and update my settings.py to

[image]

and everything worked, yay django!

Comment: Have you correctly set `STATICFILES_DIRS`  in your project's settings.py? See here for information on how to do this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Comment: do I need to set STATICFILES_DIRS? I have updated my original post with some more info

Comment: If you're running with `DEBUG = False` you need it and also call `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: ok fair enough. Do you have a link to any doco I'm a bit confused